# Getting notified about a comment that doesn't exist

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments

When I receive a new comment, I get the usual Stack Exchange notification in the corner of my screen.  However, recently it's been erroneously telling me I have a comment on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41703/575) beginning "While eplain supports loading some LaTeX packages"; neither of the comments to that answer begin that way (the second one almost does).  However, if I go to the "responses" tab of my profile page, I can see that I did get a comment, in this case [over here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42588/how-to-redefine-and-to-obfuscate-email-addresses).

Can a moderator flush this thing from my queue or does it require deeper intervention?

Answer (score 7):

The comment you're seeing in your inbox is actually [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41701/why-does-tex-not-like-usepackage/41703#comment84881_41703), but the inbox's text doesn't reflect the edit that was made.

This is a [known issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66766/global-inbox-message-not-updated-after-comment-edit) with how our Stack Exchange inbox items are stored.

Comment: You tagged this question as [meta-tag:status-bydesign]. Does this mean it's never going to be fixed?

Answer (score 5):

That comment has probably been deleted before you went to read it. Seems they don't get deleted from the inbox; I think I've encountered this behavior before as well. Perhaps a mod can confirm this, as they might be able to see deleted comments?

Comment: There is no deleted comment: I wonder if one got edited

Comment: The problem is not only that it's still in my inbox, but that it occasionally rises to the top.  This is the third time I've "seen" it.  Though interestingly, today I got two notifications of real comments and no mention of this one.

Comment: I also mentioned that I get re-notified of comments I already looked at after a while. Also I had some notifications about already comments as well.